# How to inset different Values in a specific DataGridView column

Tags: vb.net

```
btn_Click()

For Each row As DatagridviewRow In DGV.Rows
  row.Cells("Column2").Value = "Boy "
  row.Cells(Column2").Value = "Girl"
  row.Cells(Column2").Value = "Boy"
  row.Cells(Column2").Value = "Girl"
  row.Cells(Column2").Value = "Girl"
Next
```

This is the code but when I execute the code it inserts only the first value which is "Boy" throughout. But I want to insert different values.

Comment: Your code seems to have typos with the unmatching double-quotes.  It's not clear why you would write code like that: why set the value to "Boy" just to change it in the next to "Girl".  Is specifying the same column intentional?  Four spaces to indent code examples in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is incomplete code, it's sort of hard to see what's going on. Assuming that your "Next" is after the final row.Cells... You're setting the same column repeatedly in each iteration of the loop.  So you're just overwriting data repeatedly.  You should only call "row.Cells("Column2").Value = "x" once per iteration of the loop.  You will need to have some logic to determine whether to write "Boy" or "Girl" into the cell.

If you replace it with something like below (again, you will have to figure out the logic, I'm going to use some "placeholder" logic just to get working code to you), it will behave as expected.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGV.Rows
    If DGV.Rows.IndexOf(row) Mod 2 = 0 Then
        row.Cells("Column2").Value = "Boy"
    Else
        row.Cells("Column2").Value = "Girl"
    End If
Next
```

So, you will need to determine your If/Else or Case or whatever logic, and modify this, but I think this should point you in the right direction.